# Error al querer ejecutar programa

Tags: c#

Tengo un sistema en C#, al recompilar me marca que hay un error, sin embargo en la lista de errores no hay ninguno, pero por ende no me deja ejecutarlo, además de que me aparece este msj

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta depurar, o limpiar la solución. También intenta cerrando el VS y volviéndolo a abrir.

Comment: Listo, todo eso y nada, me falta reiniciar ahah